# I want to send data between two CodeIgniter function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to pass the values from one function another..

I wrote first function like this.

```
function test1(){
        $product_details[] = array(
            'product_id' => '1',
            'count'      => '2'
        );
        $this->test2($product_details);
}
```

I wrote second function like this. I have to keep this $_POST must.

```
function test2(){
        $product_details = $_POST['product_details'];
        foreach($product_details as $row){
            $this->db->insert('table',$row);
        }
}
```

It's not even printing the posted result also..
Thanks in adavance..:)

Comment: what do you expect to happen with the $product_details from the first function? That looks like dead code to me unless you were planning on passing it to the second function in which case you'd need to adjust the function signature

Comment: it will insert all the array values to the database and what about the function signature I didn't get that.

Comment: ```function test2()``` is your current function signature. If you want to pass values from test1 to test2 it should look something like ```function test2(array $product_details){...}```

Comment: In addition to what j4g0 pointed out about the second function not taking a parameter, this question is very confusing. `It's not even printing the posted result also`.... there's no "printing" code anywhere in this (or even a return of any kind) why would you expect it to "print" anything?

Comment: It's not even working by using these also..because of the $_POST on function test2. But i have to keep that in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data from test1 to test2 which it looks like in test1

```
function test1()
{
    $product_details[] = array(
        'product_id' => '1',
        'count'      => '2'
    );
    $this->test2($product_details); # here you are trying to pass the $product_details to test2
}
```

the signature of test2 has to reflect that:

```
function test2(array $product_details) # this is the function signature
{
    $product_details = $_POST['product_details']; # this line would currently override your $product_details even if you passed them from test1
    $product_details[] = $_POST['product_details']; # maybe this is what you meant?
    foreach($product_details as $row){
        $this->db->insert('table',$row); # I imagine you tried echo $row or var_dump($row) here before?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you absolutely right. But in this it's takes a null index like this -> Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4
            [quantity] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [2] => 
)

Comment: Instead of using this I got a way . Please check this and tell me can I use this.?                                          if(isset($_POST['product_details'])){
           $product_details = $_POST['product_details'];
        }                                                                                                                                              It is already working for me.

Comment: yes, that would override the $product_details that you pass from test1 only if the $_POST['product_details'] are available which seems to be what you want to achieve.

Comment: :)..Thanks a lot...D..:)